# how to fix black statusbar for fullscreen webapp in iOS 7.0.3?

Tags: ios, web-applications, fullscreen, statusbar

For iOS 7.0.0 - 7.0.2 the element

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
```

would make the status bar appear correctly at the top of the screen when running a web page in fullscreen from a homescreen icon/webclip.

With iOS 7.0.3 the bar is now completely black, no text and symbols visible.

Is there a fix for this new behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is from iOS 7 Release notes

Apps default to using the new view controller-based status bar management system.

Here is Solution:
Add a value of NO for the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key to your Info.plist.

Or

If you remove this meta line, make your background color white it will show a white status bar.

The browser will take a tint of your body background-color.

Comment: It's a web app, so the first one does not apply. Figured out meanwhile that his only happens if the homescreen icon got pushed to the device from AirWatch MDM, not if I create it myself from the browser. _sigh_ Going to get AirWatch support now ...